# Why can't the Option.expect() message be downcast as a &'static str when a panic is handled with catch_unwind?

Tags: error-handling, rust, downcast

I have the following code:

```
use std::thread;
use std::panic;

pub fn main(){
    thread::spawn(move || {
        panic::catch_unwind(|| {
            // panic!("Oh no! A horrible error.");
            let s: Option<u32> = None;
            s.expect("Nothing was there!");
        })
    })
    .join()
    .and_then(|result| {
        match result {
            Ok(ref val) => {
                println!("No problems. Result was: {:?}", val);
            }
            Err(ref err) => {
                if let Some(err) = err.downcast_ref::<&'static str>() {
                    println!("Error: {}", err);
                } else {
                    println!("Unknown error type: {:?}", err);
                }
            }
        }
        result
    });
}
```

When I trigger a `panic!` directly (by uncommenting the line in the code above), then I get an output which includes my error message:

```
Error: Oh no! A horrible error.
```

But, if I use `Option::expect(&str)`, as above, then the message cannot be downcast to `&'static str`, so I can't get the error message out:

```
Unknown error type: Any
```

How can I get the error message, and how would I find the correct type to downcast to in the general case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Option::expect`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.expect) expects a message as a `&str`, i.e. a string slice with any lifetime. You can't coerce a `&str` to a `&'static str`, as the string slice may refer to the interior of a `String` or `Box<str>` that could be freed at any time. If you were to keep a copy of the `&'static str` around, you would be able to use it after the `String` or `Box<str>` has been dropped, and that would be undefined behavior.

An importail detail is that the `Any` trait cannot hold any lifetime information (hence the `'static` bound), as lifetimes in Rust are erased at compile time. Lifetimes are used by the compiler to validate your program, but a program cannot distinguish a `&'a str` from a `&'b str` from a `&'static str` at runtime.

> [...] how would I find the correct type to downcast to in the general case?

Unfortunately, it's not easy. `Any` has a method (unstable as of Rust 1.15.1) named [`get_type_id`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/any/trait.Any.html#tymethod.get_type_id) that lets you obtain the [`TypeId`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/any/struct.TypeId.html) of the concrete object referred to by the `Any`. That still doesn't tell you explicitly what type that is, as you still have to figure out which type this `TypeId` belongs to. You would have to get the `TypeId` of many types (using [`TypeId::of`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/any/struct.TypeId.html#method.of)) and see if it matches the one you got from the `Any`, but you could do the same with `downcast_ref`.

In this instance, it turns out that the `Any` is a `String`. Perhaps `Option::expect` could eventually be specialized such that it panics with the string slice if its lifetime is `'static` and only allocates a `String` if it's not `'static`.

Comment: Thanks. I did some tests and found that even `panic!(my_str)` will end up being caught as a `String` when `my_str` is constructed at runtime. So the behaviour of `panic!()` is actually exactly what you described as your "perhaps eventually" behaviour for `Option::expect`.

Answer (score 2):

Like Francis said, you can't in general discover and cast to the type of a `panic`. However, that being said, panics have the following rules:

- If you `panic!` with a single argument, the panic will have that type. Typically this is `&'static str`.
- If you `panic!` with more than one argument, the arguments will be treated as `format!` parameters and used to create a `String` argument.

These rules are documented in the `panic` documentation: https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/fn.catch_unwind.html.

With these rules in mind, we can write a function to extract the message from a panic in any case where there is a message available to be extracted, which in practice works most of the time, because most of the time the message is either `&'static str` or `String`:

```rust
pub fn get_panic_message(panic: &Box<dyn Any + Send>) -> Option<&str> {
    panic
        // Try to convert it to a String, then turn that into a str
        .downcast_ref::<String>()
        .map(String::as_str)
        // If that fails, try to turn it into a &'static str
        .or_else(|| panic.downcast_ref::<&'static str>().map(Deref::deref))
}
```

I use this exact function in an assertions library I wrote a while ago; you can see some examples of its use in the relevant [test suite](https://github.com/Lucretiel/cool_asserts/blob/ee339b5f610cd95be6e5e5f62456cd2aa45d1ba2/src/lib.rs#L39-L70).